# load different content into single div on click or Url link

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I have a html page(for ex index.html) which has 10 links 10 places, and each time user click on any link different type of content has to load into a single div dynamically. that div has to be placed in jquery modal.the div is actually inside that html page only (index.html) but div content loads in modal depending upon user click of URL.How can I achieve this? i am new to jquery and javascript.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried something? Please show the code that you have so that someone would be able to help. Check out [the about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for more on how to ask questions here...

Comment: I am not looking it to put on another page, content is already inside the div, but it has to be popped up in a popup, which can be done usnig modal. but the problem is the content in modal has to be loaded diynamically based on the url click

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to use the [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. It's pretty straightforward to use, it operates on a selector and will load the selected element with a subset of an HTML page. So, if your div is called "fred" and you want the text from a div called "bob" on another page to be placed into the div called fred, you'd use something like this:

$('#fred').load('http://alice.com/carol.html #bob');

It's fairly well documented on the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
  <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because
  it dims out the page content.</p>
</div>

<div id="somedivwithcontent1" style="display:none">
   Text to put into the modal dialog.
</div>
```

**JS**

```
  var link = 1; //get from clicked link
  $( "#dialog-modal p" ).html( $('#somedivwithcontent'+link).html() );
  $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true
  });
```

This code will get the content of the `#somedivwithcontent` divs and place it into the paragraph of the modal dialog. Should achieve what you wanted.